# Force Forward xxx.php URLs to xxx using .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, url

I have a site that I've been running for years with the .php as part of the URL. I want to switch it over. But there are existing links out there that contain the .php in it. 
**IMPORTANT: I think a lot of people are quickly assuming that I'm asking the trivial question of "how do I remove .php from my URL?"  which I already know how to do, and it already works. My question is not quite that, so please read through carefully. This is more related to existing links, and URL unification purposes.. for SEO.**

Currently I have this in my .htaccess, so the URLs work without the .php already:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews
```

However, is there a way to detect when there is a .php included in the request and re-write the URL (or in other words, a straight up 301 forwarding) to a URL that omits the .php?

http://www.mydomain.com/our-services.php  ->   http://www.mydomain.com/our-services

After the suggestion from the 1st answer I cahnged it to this:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rhondasherwood\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound
```

Created an infinite redirect.

Comment: Are you having problems with endless redirects?

Comment: No not at all. The pages work fine with or without .php, even with added parameters (www.domain.com/services/pageid-15/tag-abc resolves to run services.php with the parameters added).

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` in `DocumentRoot`.

`MultiViews` has its drawbacks.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rhondasherwood\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L] 

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

prevent from redirect loops.

---

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rhondasherwood\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

is a cause of loop.
Have these rules in this order:

```
Options +MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: # -FrontPage-
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rhondasherwood\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1  [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound

This ruined it: "The page isn't redirecting properly" -  Do I need to re-sequence?

Comment: @jeffkee post the above comment in the question by editing it. very difficult to read when it is in comments.

Comment: Still doesn't work - updated the question again with the new file I tried (it has all the lines in file, didn't skip any so you can diagnose.. thanks for all your help so far! Very appreciated).

Comment: Actually, URLs like this: /showlisting.php/327/-1720-30th-Street-Altamont-West-Vancouver-west-vancouver-real-estate       does not work. the showlisting.php has to be force-switched to showlisting/327/..... etc.

Comment: and now, when I go straight to the above showlisting.php URL WITHOUT the .php in the address bar, I get an infinite loop. :(

Comment: @jeffkee You will have to restructure your URL. Its wont work with `.php` appearing in the middle. Or you will have to add more `RewriteRules`.

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from my mind but I remember creating an infinite redirect loop with these rules. I'll add a workaround if this does not work:

```
# Use temporary redirects for testing
# Use permanent redirects when you're satisfied
# (1) Redirect all .php requests
RewriteRule (.+)\.php $1 [L,R]

# (2) Rewrite all non-php requests
RewriteRule (.+)(?<!\.php) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I like the lookbehind.  Must remember that one.  Yes it will loop  in an "Per Directory" context because you'll get (pass1 - rule2) (pass2 - rule 1).  You need to prevent rule 1 firing on pass 2.  E.g. by adding a **`E=END:1`** flag on rule2 and a `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END} !=1` before rule one.  But +1 for the lookbehind idea :)

Comment: @TerryE: thanks. I now remember, I stopped infinite redirect problem by checking `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$` (or something along these lines). `%{REQUEST_URI}` is supposed to contain the URL requested by the browser _without any rewriting applied_.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://sicanstudios.com/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

You basically just need to use a regular expression.